# Readig old V1.X MS Access file with MS Access 2010 installed

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm new, so be gentle with me :)

I've created some C# code to read the schema definition of an MS Access files. It works great on most versions of Access, but when I try to read an older version of Access (V1.X) I'm getting the following error:

> This Property is not supported for external data sources or for databases created with a previous version of Microsoft Jet.

Here's my code:

```
private DataTable ReadSchema(string strTable)
{

        DataTable schemaTable = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider= Microsoft.JET.OleDB.4.0;data source=R:\\CB Import\\CBS.MDB");

            conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strTable, conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;

            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly);
            schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();
            reader.Close();
            conn.Close();


            DataColumn dcRec = new DataColumn("TableName", typeof(string));
            dcRec.DefaultValue = strTable;
            schemaTable.Columns.Add(dcRec);


            schemaTable.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));
            schemaTable.Columns.Add("Length", typeof(string));




            foreach (DataRow r in schemaTable.Rows)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(r["ColumnName"].ToString() + " " + r["ColumnSize"].ToString() + " " + r["DataType"].ToString() + " " + r["NumericPrecision"].ToString() + " " + r["NumericScale"].ToString());
                r["Type"] = r["DataType"];
                r["Length"] = r["ColumnSize"];

                               }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }

        return (schemaTable);


    }
```

It bombs out on this line:

```
OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly);
```

I have Access 2010 installed on my machine and even if I try to open these old troublesome files in this version of Access I still get errors about opening old versions.

This code all works apart from when I try to read an older version of Access. I can get around it by using Access 2007 (installed on another machine) and saving the database file as a 2007 version, but I'd like to be able to automate (code) this if possible? If there's another way of coding it, or something I'm messing up, please let me know.

Any help will be greatfully received and recipricated with beer, chocolate, flowers or whatever floats your boat :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's the answer - worked it out myself.

```
 public DataTable ReadSchema(string strTable, string strConnectionString, string strAccessFileName)
    {
       DataTable schemaTable = new DataTable();
       schemaTable.Columns.Add("ColumnName", typeof(string));
       schemaTable.Columns.Add("ColumnSize", typeof(Int32));
       schemaTable.Columns.Add("NumericPrecision", typeof(Int32));
       schemaTable.Columns.Add("NumericScale", typeof(Int32));
       schemaTable.Columns.Add("DataType", typeof(string));
       schemaTable.Columns.Add("Length", typeof(string));

       try
       {

           using (var con = new OleDbConnection(strConnectionString))
           {
               con.Open();
               using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + strTable + "]", con))
               using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly))
               {
                   var table = reader.GetSchemaTable();

                   foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                   {
                       Console.WriteLine(row["ColumnName"].ToString() + " " + row["ColumnSize"].ToString() + " " + row["DataType"].ToString() + " " + row["NumericPrecision"].ToString() + " " + row["NumericScale"].ToString());

                       DataRow drRecord = schemaTable.NewRow();

                       drRecord["ColumnName"] = row["ColumnName"];
                       drRecord["ColumnSize"] = row["ColumnSize"];
                       drRecord["NumericPrecision"] = row["NumericPrecision"];
                       drRecord["NumericScale"] = row["NumericScale"];
                       drRecord["DataType"] = row["DataType"];

                       schemaTable.Rows.Add(drRecord); 
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       catch (Exception Ex)
       {

           string strMessage = "Selecting schema for table " + strTable + ". " + Environment.NewLine + Ex.Message;
           MessageBox.Show(strMessage, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
           tran.strErrors = tran.strErrors + strMessage + "\r\n";
           txtErrors.Text = txtErrors.Text + strMessage + "\r\n";
       }



        return (schemaTable);


    }
```

It turns out that the bad "OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strTable, conn);" line is no good for old V1.X database files. So replaced with a "SELECT" does the trick.

More beers for me! :)